# Focus on email id and username textboxes causes the E mail Id and  password text to appear as it is inside the textbox?

Tags: android, jquery, html

[image]I have an html5 based app and I am using two input tags for entering email id and password. I am also using two labels for Email Id and Password. Now when the page loads no text appears inside these textboxes but when the user tries to enter some text in any of the textboxes and takes the cursor inside them the corresponding label text appears. How can this be removed.

The issue is only in Android and not in iOS.

```
<label for="username" id="EmailAddress"></label>
            <input type="text" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset error" name="username" id="username" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" style="-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;" />
            <label for="password" id="Password"></label>
            <input type="password" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset error" title="" name="password" id="password" value="" style="-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;"  />
```

Thanks

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't work.

Comment: No, I haven't yet found any solution via jquery/javscript or html5/css for that matter.